# jQuery refresh a div

Tags: php, jquery

I am working on a project for someone. Currently I am building a page with 2 divs, a youtube video at the left and a comment box on the right. It looks a lot like the facebook feature. Users that are logged in can also comment on a video by typing a comment inside a textarea and pressing the 'Comment' button. The page will then refresh and the comment will be visible in the comment box.

Here is the problem however; when the page refreshes, the video stops playing. Is there a way to refresh just the div with the comment box?

I know my code is not very neat, but this is just a proof of concept, so don't worry about it.

Code to get the video

```
echo "<div id='video' style='float:left; margin-right: 5px;'>";
$video_id = $_GET['i'];
$getinfo    =    new Music();
$getinfo = $getinfo->getMusicInfo($video_id);
if($getinfo){
?>
<object width="425" height="350" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/<?php echo $getinfo['link']; ?>" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"><param name="src" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/<?php echo $getinfo['link'];?>" /></object></div>
```

And this is to get the comments on a video.

```
<div id='comment_area' style='border: 1px solid green; height: 300px;'>
        <div id='comments' style='border: 1px solid blue; height:180px; overflow-y: scroll;'>
        <?php
        $getcomments = new Music();
        $getcomments = $getcomments->getMusicComments($video_id);
        if($getcomments){
            foreach($getcomments as $comment){
                echo "<br /><a href='#'>" . $comment['stagename'] . "</a><br />" . $comment['comment'] . "<br /><br />";
            }
        }
        else {echo "<br />No comments yet. Be the first to comment<br />";} ;?>
        <span id='response'></span>
        <input type='hidden' id='music_id' value='<?php echo $video_id;?>' />
        <input type='hidden' id='user' value='<?php echo $_SESSION['user'];?>' /></div><br />
        <textarea cols=50 rows=7 id='comment_box' placeholder='Comment on this'></textarea><br />
        <input type='submit' onclick="addComment()" value='add comment'>
    </div>
```

So is there a way to refresh just the second div using jQuery/javascript?

Comment: use ajax to load content at regular interval ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery's `load()` function and specify the content to load:

```
$('#comment_area').load('mypage.php #comment_area');
```

Of course, you'll also need to submit the comment via ajax as well. So another option would be to submit the comment using ajax, then send back a confirmation that it worked, and just append the comment to the comment list using javascript.

As a side note, I don't see where you are encoding your comments to prevent XSS. Don't forget to do that.

Comment: Ok, so I am going to have to change my code anyway? Instead of using OOP, I have to use ajax/jquery?

Comment: Ajax and OO server-side code are not mutually exclusive. But if you want the page to submit/retrieve data from the server without refreshing, ajax is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish this would be to use jquery's $.ajax method. This would allow you to post the comment and read/update the comments all without a page reload. Because it looks like you already have a "getMusicComments" method in your php it should be fairly simple to call that method with ajax to retrieve the comments.

Read up on jquery $.ajax [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: But the problem is that getMusicComments is a PHP function. A method of the Music class to be precise. I don't think I can call a PHP method from ajax?